# Request not going with `$.ajax` call in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ajax

I need to make an ajax call with jQuery and need to pass diffrent ajax options base on the result of a `if/else` condition.

This is how I tried it:

```
var url = 'form_submission.php';
if (imgAttached) {
  var params     = $form.serializeArray(),
      formData   = new FormData(),
      files      = $form.find('[name="images"]')[0].files;

  $.each(files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('images-' + i, file);
  });
  
  $.each(params, function(i, val) {
    formData.append(val.name, val.value);
  });

  var ajaxOptions  =  " url:"+url
      ajaxOptions +=  ",type:"+'post'
      ajaxOptions +=  ",data:"+formData
      ajaxOptions +=  ",cache:"+false
      ajaxOptions +=  ",contentType:"+false
      ajaxOptions +=  ",processData:"+false; 

} else {
  var formData = $form.serialize();

  var ajaxOptions  =  " url:"+url
      ajaxOptions +=  ",type:"+'post'
      ajaxOptions +=  ",data:"+formData;
}
```

This is how I call ajax request from outside `if/else`:

```
$.ajax({        
  ajaxOptions,        
  beforeSend: function() {},
  success: function(json) {}
)}
```

My problem is request is not going with `ajaxOptions` and when I trying with standard way its working. Can anybody tell what would be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax()` function takes an **object** as a parameter i.e. it should have **key-value pairs**.

Here, in `$.ajax({ ajaxOptions, .....})`, `ajaxOptions` is a **string** formed by concatenation, instead of being **key-value pairs**.

**Expected**

```
url: 'form_submission.php',
method: 'POST'
```

**Actual**

```
"url: 'form_submission.php', method: 'POST'"
```

To fix this, create an `ajaxOptions` object and pass it to the `$.ajax()` function by extracting the properties using **spread** operator.

```
if (imgAttached) {
  .
  .
  .
  const ajaxOptions = {
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  };
} else {
  .
  .
  .
  const ajaxOptions = {
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
  };
}

$.ajax({        
  ...ajaxOptions,        
  beforeSend: function() {},
  success: function(json) {}
)}
```